# Use mathrm + isomath with beamer

Tags: beamer, math-operators, isomath

I use isomath to make greek letters italic by default. Sometimes I want an upright operator. Then I use `\mathrm`. It works in the report, but not when trying to use it in my presentation.

This is a minimal non-working example (the \Delta is typeset as a '):

```
\documentclass[intlimits]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{isomath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
 \frame{Difference in angle is $\mathrm{\Delta}\theta$}
\end{document}
```

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{isomath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
Difference in angle is $\mathrm{\Delta}\theta$
\end{document}
```

So how can I make it work in Beamer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `beamer` seems to be unable to use greek letters for operators unless either `\usefonttheme{serif}` or `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` has been used. `\usefonttheme{default}` fails. Can it be a bug?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `isomath` with `beamer`, Greek letters will be in a different font than the standard sans serif; for instance

```
\documentclass[intlimits]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{isomath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

$\alpha+\beta-1$

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

prints the disputable output

[image]

You may want to use `arev`, instead:

```
\documentclass[intlimits]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{isomath}

\usepackage{arevtext,arevmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

Difference in angle is $\upDelta\theta$

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is one thing. Another thing is to create a macro that is suitable for operators. Is it possible to renewcommand \matrhm so it creates \upDelta, or is there another more appropriate macro for math operators. I also have the Gamma function, and Exp as in exponential distribution.